# App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection

Tags: xcode, swift, nsapptransportsecurity

I added the `NsAppTransportSecurity` as dictionary and added the key `NsAllowArbitaryLoads` exactly how everybody said but it does not work for me. 
I made a clean rebuild of the project, but I still the same error.

[image: Error and Info.plist]

Comment: This should do it. Make sure you're editing the correct plist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done like this

NSAppTransportSecurity <- Type Dictionary 
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads <- Type Boolean Value YES

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should be done like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>your.domain.name.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: This might be "better" but I have multiple projects that use his method and it works great.