# Escape Character in URL - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, url

I'm pulling a URL from a string and turning that into a button to a WebView of the link.

This is the error I'm getting...

```
2015-11-10 18:58:05.159 MPSTApp[520:169178] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "https:/www.facebook.com/prontosantateresa -- file:///" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme file"
```

For this instance the string is https://www.facebook.com/prontosantateresa but I believe it's using the double // as an escape character.

The code calling the url link is such -

```
var anchorLink: String?

func loadWebPage(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: anchorLink!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated issue. Since I was using an app browser, it didn't need to use UIApplication.canOpenUrl(). 
So, to resolve this I replaced the event method with below code in

```
@IBAction func website1ButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
  if self.anchorLink != nil{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("categoryDetailToWebSegue", sender: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what the error message says: It tries to open a file:// url. So, your algorithm for retrieving the https:// url seems to do something wrong and turn "//" into "/". It could also come handy to add the  [NSAllowArbitaryLoads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703226/app-transport-security-policy-requires-the-use-of-a-secure-connection) key to your Info.plist.

Comment: Added the key to the .plist already.  Not sure why it's only pulling "/"

Comment: What are you doing in order to extract the URL from the text? I think that's the cause for your issues.